# restoreCompletedTransactions doesn't restore all purchases in sandbox

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have an iOS IAP store that consists of five non-consumable purchases. No Apple hosted content. Just simple IAPs that unlock features in my app.

When I call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]`, then `- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
 updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` is called with only three of the five IAPs. It is not called again.

However then when I go to purchase one of the non-restored IAPs, I get the dialog "You've already purchased this. Would you like to get it again for free?". So it would seem Apple already has a record of the sandbox purchase.

In the simulator, `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` is not called at all.

All five IAPs are approved in iTunes Connect and have been purchased by users.

Comment: Are you receiving a call to paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:?

Comment: @AaronGolden, afraid not.

Comment: Any news on this issue? Seems that I have it as well :/

Comment: @MaciekCzarnik I've removed IAPs in the latest version of my app. I never managed to fix this.

Comment: Btw - are you able to reproduce it, or one of your clients has reported it to you?

Comment: @MaciekCzarnik Yes, I had reproduced it myself.

Comment: Hmm, I asked because in my app it has been reported by a client, and it come up that it has been caused by confusion between using live Apple Id on production and TestFlight - they both use different databases of purchased content

Comment: @MaciekCzarnik It's been a while but I think users had trouble with it as well. I would tell them to just go through the purchase again and they wouldn't be double-charged.